# Where is the mistake in this argument about number of different balls with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Out of $N$ distinguishable balls, I draw $A$ balls with replacement. On average, there are
$$B=N\left(1-\left(1-\frac 1 N\right)^A\right)$$
different balls.

I am interested in how many times a drawn ball is drawn on average. I have two approaches:

1) There are A draws and B different balls drawn, therefore there are on average $\frac A B$ draws that correspond to each different ball.

2) Each drawn ball is drawn once + on average $\frac {A-1} N$ (that is the expected value of a binomial of parameters $A-1$ and $1/N$, or the average number of draws, out of $A-1$, that correspond to our selected ball (probability of $1/N$)).

These two approaches lead to two different results ($\frac A B$ versus $1+\frac {A-1} N$), yet seemingly describe the same experiment.

There must be an error, either in the math or in my intuition of the experiments but I can't get a hold on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good and subtle question. The short answer is that the two arguments are counting different things, and you need to be clear about what you want to count.

[An analogy: This is an instance of a [sampling bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias) (see also [friendship paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox)): suppose you're trying to determine how full buses are on average. You may poll the buses and find that half the buses were nearly empty, and half of them were nearly full. If you poll the passengers instead, most of them will say their bus was nearly full.]

I'll recast your problem as follows, because I find this easier to talk about: suppose you throw $A$ apples into $N$ bins, choosing for each apple $j$ a bin $B_j$ uniformly at random from among the $N$ bins (and independently of the other $A - 1$ apples). [Usually one throws *balls* into bins, but I'm using apples here to avoid confusion with the balls of the question, and because of the coincidence with the name $A$.]

In any given trial (i.e. for a certain way of throwing apples into bins), let $S_i$ denote the size of the $i$th bin. So you have a bunch of $N$ nonnegative integers $S_1, \dots, S_N$, such that $S_1 + \dots + S_N = A$. Further, let $M$ be the number of nonempty bins (in other words, the number of positive $S_i$).

Now your question becomes: what is the size of a nonempty bin on average? This may mean several different things you may want to count:

- For a particular *bin* $i$, the expected size (averaged over trials) it has among the times it is nonempty, namely $\operatorname{E}[S_i \mid S_i > 0]$. This is $\frac{A}{E[M]} = \frac{A}{B}$, as proved in the other answer.
- The expected size of the bin a particular *apple* $j$ is in, namely $\operatorname{E}[S_{B_j}]$. This is what your second argument counts. For an apple $j$ that goes into bin $B_j$, the expected number of *other* apples in that bin is $\frac{A-1}{N}$ (as you calculated), as each of the other $A-1$ apples falls into this bin with probability $\frac1N$. So the expected size of this bin is $E[S_{B_j}] = 1 + \frac{A-1}{N}$.

The reason the two are different (count different things) is that a particular apple is more likely to be in a larger bin (that's what makes the bin larger!). So the second one is not the expected number of apples in a nonempty bin; it's rather (one more than) the expected number of "neighbours" an apple has. (You're averaging over apples instead of averaging over bins.)

[There are actually a couple of yet other things you might want to count:

- The expected value (average over trials) of the average size (over bins) of the nonempty bins, namely $\operatorname{E}[\sum_i S_i / M]$. As $\sum_i S_i = A$, this is simply $\operatorname{E}[A/M] = A\operatorname{E}[1/M]$. (Your first argument corresponds to this, but the number you got corresponds to the previous one... there's some catch here that I'm not at the moment able to understand.)
- The expected size of the average size of a bin an apple is in, namely $\operatorname{E}[(\sum_j S_{B_j}) / A]$. This fortunately by linearity of expectation is the same as the earlier number $1 + \frac{A-1}{N}$.]

As an example, let's consider a particular assignment of apples to bins, and take the averages for this case (we'll be taking the "space" average rather than the "time" average, but that will serve to illustrate). Suppose you have three nonempty bins, with $6$, $1$ and $2$ apples respectively. The average number of apples in a nonempty bin (averaged over nonempty bins) is $\dfrac{6 + 1 + 2}{3} = 3$, while the average over apples of the size of the bin containing that apple is $\dfrac{6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 1 + 2 + 2}{9} = 4.\bar{5}$. Clearly a different number.

In fact, even in general, the latter number $1 + \frac{A-1}{N}$ can be seen as counting $\dfrac{\sum_{i} S_i^2}{A} = \dfrac{\sum_i S_i^2}{\sum_i S_i}$. So it's a quantity that increases with the *variance* of the $S_i$s, rather than being their mean / expected value.

---

In fact, for fixed $A$ and large $N$ (or in a regime where $A = o(N)$), it's interesting to compare the numbers asympotically: the former, namely $A/E[M] = A/B$, can be shown to be $1 + \dfrac{A-1}{2N} + O\left(\frac1{N^2}\right)$, as compared with the second number number $1 + \dfrac{A-1}{N}$.

---

If it helps, here's a sample run from $20$ trials of a computer simulation of assigning $A=15$ apples to $N=10$ bins.

```
   1    2    2    1    3    1    3    1    0    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.07 
   1    2    0    1    2    2    1    4    1    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.20 
   4    1    0    2    1    0    3    2    1    1  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.47 
   1    2    3    0    1    2    0    0    4    2  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.60 
   1    2    1    0    3    1    2    1    3    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.07 
   2    1    3    4    1    1    1    0    1    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.33 
   0    1    0    1    3    1    2    2    1    4  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.47 
   1    2    0    1    2    1    3    0    4    1  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.47 
   2    1    1    2    2    2    3    1    1    0  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 1.93 
   4    4    1    0    0    2    1    1    1    1  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.73 
   1    1    1    1    1    3    2    3    2    0  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.07 
   1    0    4    1    0    1    3    2    0    3  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.73 
   1    3    2    3    1    1    1    0    3    0  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.33 
   0    1    0    1    1    3    4    0    3    2  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.73 
   1    2    2    2    0    2    4    0    0    2  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.47 
   3    1    0    1    3    2    0    0    2    3  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.47 
   0    2    0    1    0    4    1    1    3    3  Average S_i 2.14, Average S_B_j 2.73 
   1    2    2    0    1    1    5    2    1    0  Average S_i 1.88, Average S_B_j 2.73 
   1    2    1    2    1    0    1    3    3    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.07 
   1    2    1    3    1    3    1    2    0    1  Average S_i 1.67, Average S_B_j 2.07 
Average over trials for each of the 10 bins:
1.59 1.79 1.85 1.69 1.69 1.83 2.28 1.92 2.12 1.75 
Average over trials for each of the 15 apples:
2.25 2.20 2.40 2.20 2.25 2.20 2.55 2.55 2.40 2.25 2.40 2.65 2.45 2.70 2.35
```

Comment: Thanks for the good write-up! I've got a better intuition of the situation now.

Comment: @doc: Glad to have helped. I've rewritten the answer now -- you can take another look and see if it helps further (or confuses!).

Comment: What would be the probability distribution of finding i=1,2,3,... apples in a non-empty bin?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a ball and denote the number of times that it is drawn by $D$. Then:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(D\mid D>0\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{A}kP\left(D=k\mid D>0\right)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{A}kP\left(D=k\right)}{P\left(D>0\right)}=\frac{\frac{A}{N}}{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{A}}=\frac{A}{B}$$

Let $E_k$ be the event that the chosen ball is drawn at the $k$-th drawing.
Then:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(D\mid E_k\right)=1+\frac{A-1}{N}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that is my intuition too. However I fail to see how the events $D>0$ and $E_k$ are different. If $D>0$, if and only if there exists a $k$ such that $E_k$ is true.

Comment: $D>0$ stands for $E_{1}\cup\cdots\cup E_{A}$. So if $A>1$ then the events $D>0$ and $E_k$ are not the same.